# Async Await - Need some guidance

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task, directory-walk

I have tried many different ways to get this to work, and I am sure that is not the proper way to wire up async/await for multi threading. Here is what I have so far. It is a directory walker that I attempted to make async. I know that you don't see any async or await keywords and that is because I was unsuccessful, but that is what I am trying to do. Right now it runs in a console application but I will abstract and refactor later once I get a working POC.  Any guidance is appreciated.

```
    static void RunProgram(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var dir in _directoriesToProcess)
            {
                var newTask = CreateNewTask(dir, ct);
                _tasks.Add(newTask);
            }

            while (_tasks.Count > 0)
            {
                lock (_collectionLock)
                {
                    var t = _tasks.Where(x => x.IsCompleted == true).ToList();
                    if (t != null)
                        foreach (var task in t)
                        {
                            _tasks.Remove(task);
                        }
                }
            }

            OutputFiles();
            StopAndCleanup();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(LogColor.Red, "Error: " + ex.Message, false);
            _cts.Cancel();
        }
    }


    static Task CreateNewTask(string Path, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetDirectoryFiles(Path, ct), ct);
    }

    static void GetDirectoryFiles(string Path, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        if (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            List<string> subDirs = new List<string>();
            int currentFileCount = 0;
            try
            {
                currentFileCount = Directory.GetFiles(Path, _fileExtension).Count();
                subDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(Path).ToList();

                lock (_objLock)
                {
                    _overallFileCount += currentFileCount;
                    Log(LogColor.White, "- Current path: " + Path);
                    Log(LogColor.Yellow, "--  Sub directory count: " + subDirs.Count);
                    Log(LogColor.Yellow, "--  File extension: " + _fileExtension);
                    Log(LogColor.Yellow, "--  Current count: " + currentFileCount);
                    Log(LogColor.Red, "--  Running total: " + _overallFileCount);
                    _csvBuilder.Add(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", Path, subDirs.Count, _fileExtension, currentFileCount));
                    Console.Clear();
                    Log(LogColor.White, "Running file count: " + _overallFileCount, false, true);
                }

                foreach (var dir in subDirs)
                {
                    lock (_collectionLock)
                    {
                        var newTask = CreateNewTask(dir, ct);
                        _tasks.Add(newTask);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log(LogColor.Red, "Error: " + ex.Message, false);
                _cts.Cancel();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like c#--consider adding that tag.

Comment: As far as I know, there are no async APIs for file system enumeration. Even if there were, unless you're working on an SSD (or similar), parallelizing will make it slower and put unnecessary stress on the disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any issue with what you're trying to do, just be cautious about uncontrolled concurrency e.g. reading too many directories at once on different threads.  Context switching could end up making it slower.

Instead of doing things as side effects in your methods, try returning the collected values. e.g.

```
static async Task<IEnumerable<DirectoryStat>> GetDirectoryFiles(string path, string fileExtension, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var thisDirectory = await Task.Run(() => /* Get directory file count and return a DirectoryStat object */);
    var subDirectoriesResults = await Task.WhenAll(Directory.GetDirectories(path).Select(dir => GetDirectoryFiles(dir, fileExtension, ct)));

    return (new[] { thisDirectory }).Concat(subDirectoryResults);
}
```

You can then iterate them later and pull the data you need from `DirectoryStat` (and sum your file counts as per `_overallFileCount` etc)

NOTE: Untested :)

Comment: This is more towards what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can run Synchronous Code Async with `Task.Run(() => { //code });`
Also change your Return Type to `Task`so you can `await` it
I would rewrite you code as follows:

```
static void RunProgram(CancellationToken ct)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var dir in _directoriesToProcess)
        {
            var newTask = CreateNewTask(dir, ct);
            _tasks.Add(newTask);
        }

        //change your while so it does not execute all the time
        while (_tasks.Count > 0)
        {
            lock (_collectionLock)
            {
                var tsk = _tasks.FirstOrDefault();
                        if (tsk != null)
                        {
                            if (tsk.Status <= TaskStatus.Running)
                                await tsk;
                            _tasks.Remove(tsk);
                        }
            }
        }

        OutputFiles();
        StopAndCleanup();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log(LogColor.Red, "Error: " + ex.Message, false);
        _cts.Cancel();
    }
}


static Task CreateNewTask(string Path, CancellationToken ct)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetDirectoryFiles(Path, ct), ct);
}

//always use Task (or Task<T>) as return so you can await the process
static async Task GetDirectoryFiles(string Path, CancellationToken ct)
{
    if (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        //Insert Magic
        await Task.Run(() => {
            List<string> subDirs = new List<string>();
            int currentFileCount = 0;
            try
            {
                currentFileCount = Directory.GetFiles(Path, _fileExtension).Count();
                subDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(Path).ToList();

                lock (_objLock)
                {
                    _overallFileCount += currentFileCount;
                    Log(LogColor.White, "- Current path: " + Path);
                    Log(LogColor.Yellow, "--  Sub directory count: " + subDirs.Count);
                    Log(LogColor.Yellow, "--  File extension: " + _fileExtension);
                    Log(LogColor.Yellow, "--  Current count: " + currentFileCount);
                    Log(LogColor.Red, "--  Running total: " + _overallFileCount);
                    _csvBuilder.Add(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", Path, subDirs.Count, _fileExtension, currentFileCount));
                    Console.Clear();
                    Log(LogColor.White, "Running file count: " + _overallFileCount, false, true);
                }

                foreach (var dir in subDirs)
                {
                    lock (_collectionLock)
                    {
                        var newTask = CreateNewTask(dir, ct);
                        _tasks.Add(newTask);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(LogColor.Red, "Error: " + ex.Message, false);
            _cts.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was really hoping to get some help with using Task.WaitAll/Task.WhenAll using the locking object slows down the walker.